# Nativescript push notifications with 3rd party Push services

Tags: javascript, android, ios, push-notification, nativescript

I'm getting ready to build a Cross-Platform app using NativeScript and was wondering if the Push notification package they offer supports integration with 3rd party push services. I would think so, but I notice some of the sites for the push services actually list the Dev Platforms they support. Carnival for example has a special package for React-Native. Any one have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that you have already found your answer in Nativescript repository but in order to share the knowledge with the community I am going to post the link to the discussion [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/71#issuecomment-206948952)

As Brad Martin said - Yes - you can use 3rd parties services.
Anyone interested can see his article on that matter [here](http://bradmartin.net/2015/12/28/use-google-cloud-messaging-for-push-notifications-with-nativescript/)

Comment: I intend to use a different 3rd party service other than GCM. I'll be sure to document when it takes to do that once I complete it.